# Is there a way to get more than 10 markers in map

Tags: javascript, laravel, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to get nearby place at my current location .The problem that I'm facing at the moment is that ,I can only get back 10 markers on the map ,it does not give back anymore locations ,is there a way to bypass or fix this problem ,apparently I have read online that Google limits you only to 10 markers

googleMaps.js:

```
//Variable init
    var map;
    var infowindow;
    var service;
    var markers = [];
    //var myLatLng= new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433,151.1956316);

    //Dom init
    $('#details').hide();
    $('#gym').prop('checked', true);
    $('#park').prop('checked', true);
    $('#store').prop('checked', true);
    $('#museum').prop('checked', true);
    //$('#zoo').prop('checked', true);
    $('#cafe').prop('checked', true);

    //Function init
    geoLocationInit();

    //Google maps area
    function geoLocationInit() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, fail);
        } else {
            alert("Browser not supported");
        }
    }

    function success(position) {
        var latval = position.coords.latitude;
        var Ingval = position.coords.longitude;
        myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latval, Ingval);
        initMap(myLatLng);
    }

    function fail() {
        alert("it fails");
    }

    function initMap(myLatLng) {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: myLatLng,
            zoom: 12
        });

        var request = {
            location: myLatLng,
            radius: 8047,
            types: ['cafe', 'gym', 'park', 'store', 'museum']
        };

        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
        map.addListener('idle', performSearch);
    }




    function callback(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                addMaker(results[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    function addMaker(place) {
        service.getDetails({
            placeId: place.place_id
        }, function (place, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    name: place.name,
                    map: map,
                    position: place.geometry.location,
                    types: place.types
                });

                markers.push(marker);

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                    var review = [];
                    if (undefined !== place.reviews && place.reviews.length) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < place.reviews.length; i++) {
                            if (place.reviews[i].text) {
                                review.push('<b>Author Name:</b>&nbsp;' + place.reviews[i].author_name + '</br>' + '<b>Review:</b>&nbsp;' + place.reviews[i].text + '</br>');
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        review.push('Not Available');
                    }

                    infowindow.setContent(place.name);
                    infowindow.open(map, this);
                    $('#details').show();
                    $('#name').html(place.name);
                    $('#rating').html(place.rating + ' ' + 'Star(s)');
                    $('#address').html(place.adr_address);
                    $('#review').html(review);
                });
            }
        });
    }

    //Gym markers
    function gymMarkers() {
        markerType = '';
        var check = $('#gym').is(':checked');
        if (check) {
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < markers[i].types.length; j++) {
                    if (markers[i].types[j] == "gym") {
                        markers[i].setVisible(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < markers[i].types.length; j++) {
                    if (markers[i].types[j] == "gym") {
                        markers[i].setVisible(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Park markers
    function parkMarkers() {
        var check = $('#park').is(':checked');
        if (check) {
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < markers[i].types.length; j++) {
                    if (markers[i].types[j] == "park") {
                        markers[i].setVisible(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < markers[i].types.length; j++) {
                    if (markers[i].types[j] == "park") {
                        markers[i].setVisible(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Store markers
    function storeMarkers() {
        var check = $('#store').is(':checked');
        if (check) {
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < markers[i].types.length; j++) {
                    if (markers[i].types[j] == "store") {
                        markers[i].setVisible(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < markers[i].types.length; j++) {
                    if (markers[i].types[j] == "store") {
                        markers[i].setVisible(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Museum markers
    function museumMarkers() {
        var check = $('#museum').is(':checked');
        if (check) {
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < markers[i].types.length; j++) {
                    if (markers[i].types[j] == "museum") {
                        markers[i].setVisible(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < markers[i].types.length; j++) {
                    if (markers[i].types[j] == "museum") {
                        markers[i].setVisible(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Zoo markers
    // function zooMarkers() {
    //     var check = $('#zoo').is(':checked');
    //     if (check) {
    //         for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    //             for (var j = 0; j < markers[i].types.length; j++) {
    //                 if (markers[i].types[j] == "zoo") {
    //                     markers[i].setVisible(true);
    //                 }
    //             }
    //         }
    //     } else {
    //         for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    //             for (var j = 0; j < markers[i].types.length; j++) {
    //                 if (markers[i].types[j] == "zoo") {
    //                     markers[i].setVisible(false);
    //                 }
    //             }
    //         }
    //     }
    // }

    //Cafe markers
    function cafeMarkers() {
        var check = $('#cafe').is(':checked');
        if (check) {
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < markers[i].types.length; j++) {
                    if (markers[i].types[j] == "cafe") {
                        markers[i].setVisible(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < markers[i].types.length; j++) {
                    if (markers[i].types[j] == "cafe") {
                        markers[i].setVisible(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

front.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')


    <!-- This is a *view* - HTML markup that defines the appearance of your UI -->
    <div id='searchBar'>
        <p>Search: <strong data-bind="text: location"></strong></p>
        <p><input type='checkbox' onclick="gymMarkers();" id='gym'> Gyms </p>
        <p><input type='checkbox' onclick="parkMarkers();" id='park'>Parks </p>
        <p><input type='checkbox' onclick="storeMarkers();" id='store'> Stores </p>
        <p><input type='checkbox' onclick="museumMarkers();" id='museum'> Museums </p>
        <p><input type='checkbox' onclick="zooMarkers();" id='zoo'> Zoos </p>
        <p><input type='checkbox' onclick="cafeMarkers();" id='cafe'> cafe </p>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        {{--Google maps--}}
        <div id="map"></div>

        {{--Cafe details--}}
        <div id="details" style="visibility:false">
            <table class="table table-bordered" style="width: 500px; margin-top: 10px;">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;"><b>Description</b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="150">Name</td>
                    <td id="name"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="150">Rating</td>
                    <td id="rating"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="150">Address</td>
                    <td id="address"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="150">User Review</td>
                    <td id="review"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

        {{--Review--}}
        <div>
            <ul class="reviews"></ul>
        </div>
        {{--Example--}}
        <div>
            <ul class="example"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

[Image of map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4HnI.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are using places nearby search in your JavaScript code. The nearby search can return up to 60 results in 3 pages. The Places API web service documentation says the following:

> By default, each Nearby Search or Text Search returns up to 20 establishment results per query; however, each search can return as many as 60 results, split across three pages. If your search will return more than 20, then the search response will include an additional value — next_page_token. Pass the value of the next_page_token to the pagetoken parameter of a new search to see the next set of results.

In places library of Maps JavaScript API the behavior is similar. The callback function of `nearbySearch()` [1] method returns the third parameter of type `PlaceSearchPagination` [2]. The pagination has a property `hasNextPage` that allows to check if there are more results. If so, you can call the pagination `nextPage()` method.

There is an example that demonstrates how to use the pagination with nearby search:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search-pagination

Also, note that Places API doesn't work as a database search, and doesn't return all results. It returns only prominent results for a specified area. How Google decides which results are prominent and which are not I cannot say. So, if you get less than 20 results in the first page this means that Google cannot find 20 prominent results for this area.

I hope my answer clarifies your doubt.

[1] https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlacesService

[2] https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlaceSearchPagination